# spatio-temporal density analysis of point patterns with lgcp

Tags: r, point-process

I am trying to use the R package [lgcp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lgcp/index.html) to estimate density based on a point pattern over time. I follow the example given by the authors of the package in [this article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v063i07/v63i07.pdf), but even the first step (copied from page 25 in the article) fails.

My data is available here [bad-sample.RData](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99038959/data/bad-sample.RData) (21 kb) and it consists of two objects: xyt and my.weights (both used in the function call below).

and the failing code is this:

```
library(lgcp)
load("bad-sample.RData")
minc <- minimum.contrast.spatiotemporal(xyt, 
 model = "exponential",
 method = "g",
 transform = log,
 spatial.dens = density.ppp(xyt, weights=my.weights),
 temporal.intens =  muEst(xyt))
```

The error message is:

```
[Univariate spatio-temporal minimum contrast]
Spatial: Time-averaged PCF estimation...
|============================================| 100%
Spatial: Starting values are (0.07, 4.04); optimising exponential 

correlation function...Error in optim(par = spatial.startvals, fn = g.diff.single, ghat = nonpar$iso[-1],  : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
In addition: Warning message:
In CovarianceFct(useq, model = model, param = c(mean = NA, variance = ps[2],  :
  The function is obsolete. Use 'RFcov' instead
```

The error message: "function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters", made me try different samples, but I get the same error with other samples too.

Have someone here at CrossValidated used lgcp successfully for spatio-temporal analysis of point patterns? Do you, or anyone else, have any advice on what I could try to overcome the problem above?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the code calls `spatstat::ginhom` on the point pattern corresponding to each individual time. For e.g. `t=5` you only have one point and the result returned by `spatstat` is `NaN`. This goes into `optim` and you get an error. Maybe you can pool some time points together to have more data at each time point.